# Publishing Visual studio project on localhost

Tags: visual-studio

I tried to search about this but doesn't answer my question. I'm currently testing my project on localhost mostly and I can't test my project if Visual studio isn't debugging so I was wondering if I have to publish my whole project to localhost or something? And if so, how do I do it and do I need something like apache or wamp for that?

The project is ASP.NET Web Forms

Comment: Provide more details.
What type of a project (MVC .Net, MVC core, winforms(?))? What do you want to test?

Comment: it's web forms, edited main post

Comment: And what do you want to test?

Comment: I want to be able to use my application without having visual studio debugging and without having to publish whole project on the real server

Comment: Why don't you just run your project without debugging (Ctrl+F5)?

Comment: Oh I never thought about this... After all this time i just got used to pressing F5

Comment: I will write that as an answer and would appreciate if you accepted it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just start your project without debugging (Ctrl+F5) or click on Debug -> Start without debugging.

Comment: Thanks a lot though, even if it's a dumb question i never realized this, you just saved me a lot of time from debugging everytime